# STREAM video from ANDROID device to OPENCV real time

Tags: android, opencv, stream, usb, google-gdk

I'm working with the google glass (it is considered as a normal android device) and openCV Lib (c++). I need to transfer (REAL-TIME) the video source from the android camera to visual studio and process it on my PC. I am not processing the video directly in the glass because it is too computationally expensive. I tried to stream using rtsp, http.. protocols but the quality of the frames is bad and there is an inconvenient latency.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone of you know how to stream the video via USB and get it on visual studio. I read something about using ADB but it does not seem to have a real-time function. 
Otherwise I'am all ears for any suggestion.

thank you in advance!!
Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adb forward](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to foward a certain TCP port over USB.

That should allow you to open a socket between the Android device and your host PC through USB data transfer, which should give you fast enough speeds to send frames to the PC in real-time and analyse them in OpenCV. You can just send the frames as bytes over the socket.

Comment: do you think this tutorial will help me?  http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/ how can i get the video on OpenCV afterwards? how can i manipulate bytes and get the video?

Comment: Yes. Plug your Glass in your pc, and run adb forward tcp:1234 tcp:1234 and then open a socket to your host on port 1234. After that you can directly use a ByteBuffer to send frames to the host PC. It should be faster than through WiFi that's for sure.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new on this.. could you suggest me any tutorial? thank you!